# My P5.js sketch don't work in python SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: javascript, python, html, p5.js

I have downloaded the p5.js example sketch file and try to make it work with a python SimpleHTTPServer but when I run the program the local host page looks blank. Here is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.9/p5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.9/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.9/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
        <script src="sketch.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is my sketch.js file:

```
var blockSize;
var blockSize;
var blocks = [];
var turnOwner;
var winner;
var mode;
var selected;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(800, 700);

    blockSize = height / 11;
    turnOwner = 1;

}

function draw() {
    background(100);
}
```

When I click on the html itself it works but when I try to acces it through local host it dose not work. Thanks for helping :)

Also my server console when I try to acces the folder with the files in it

```
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/) ...
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Aug/2017 21:17:41] "GET /project/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

P.S: I double checked the file directory of the python server.

Comment: Please use the [developer tools](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools) and check the JavaScript console for any errors.

Comment: There were no errors in the JS console, I am using chrome for this if that matters.

Comment: What about in the network tab? Is everying loading correctly? Please note that your sketch should just be a blank gray rectangle.

Comment: What happens if you change the `https` occurences to use `http` instead?